# check php running on windows

Tags: php

I have installed XAMPP 1.7  on my windows 7. As expected, PHP is already included in this installer package. I look at XAMPP installed folder on my hard drive (`C:\xampp`) and it does have one folder named php.

Now, when I open XAMPP and take a look at Windows Task Manager, I see both apache and mysql appear on process tab and service tab but php does not appear on any of those tabs.

I just want to check whether php is runninng or not? Could you tell me why the above checking failed Or PHP is really not running at that time (please note that I have already activated XAMM at this time).

Comment: You should accept an answer if something helped, see my answer if you need help running php scripts specifically with xampp.

Answer (score 4):

PHP does not have a running process when being invoked through apache.  Instead, the PHP interpreter is executed for each apache request.  To test if it is running, put

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

in a file named `index.php` and hit it in your browser.

If PHP is working, as it should with a default install of XAMPP, then you should see some information about your PHP installation on that page.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, apache will run php when it deems necessary (eg. when there's a new request). Try putting a script in C:\xampp\htdocs\mystuff (say, script.php) and go to //localhost/mystuff/script.php with your browser of preference — if it shows up, it's running as it should.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not run as a process through XAMPP, it is actually run through apache module.

If you want to check if php is running, in the document root, create a empty file.php with `<?php phpinfo();` inside of it and run that in your browser.